# How to detect one resource file is from jar or from file?

Tags: java, resources, classpath

I want to load one resource file from classpath. This file may be in a jar file or just a separate file. How can I know that ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick assuming that `MyClass` is a class in the same `ClassLoader` or a child `ClassLoader` of the one that contains your resource file.

```
MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/my/resource")
```

> Finds a resource with a given name. The rules for searching resources
>   associated with a given class are implemented by the defining class
>   loader of the class. This method delegates to this object's class
>   loader. If this object was loaded by the bootstrap class loader, the
>   method delegates to
>   **ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)**.

More details [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String))

The proposal above provide your resource as a `InputStream`, if you want to have it as an `URL` use `MyClass.class. getResource("/path/to/my/resource")` instead